# Erro de referência pacote Bde no Delphi

Tags: delphi, embarcadero

Estou precisando recompilar uma aplicação legado que veio de uma empresa que adquirimos.

Neste projeto tem a referência para o que eu acredito ser o pacote ([Bde](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Bde.DBTables)), que até onde eu sei foi descontinuado.

Estou utilizando a versão 10.3 do Delphi com o Embarcadero Delphi 10.3 Version 26.0.36039.7899.

Quando o fonte é carregado aparece uma série de erros referente a esse pacote. O primeiro erro é **"Cannot resolve unit name 'DBTables' at line 7"**. Após este erro vem uma série de erros relacionados à classes dentro desse namespace, sendo essas classes `TQuery` e `TDatabase`.

Pesquisei quase a manhã toda na internet e não consegui encontrar uma forma de resolver isso. Tentei baixar um arquivo BPL (bdertl70.bpl) para incluir como pacote, porém também não deu certo.

O que eu já tentei:

1. Tools > GetIt Package Manager > Buscar pelo pacote
2. Buscar no google diversas referências sobre esse pacote
3. Baixar e tentar carregar o pacote via Conponent > Install package
4. Pesquisa realizada no SOEN e SOPT

Eu não tenho experiência profissional com Delphi. talvez seja uma coisa simples e eu não estou conseguindo ver o caminho. Qualquer ajuda é muito bem vinda.

**EDIT:**
O que eu preciso é conseguir incluir a referência nesse projeto para que possa realizar a compilação. Atualmente não sigo fazer isso e por este motivo não consigo compilar o código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No portal da Embarcadero, na sua conta, onde mostra os downloads disponíveis, tem lá o **BDE Installer for RAD Studio**.

O BDE foi descontinuado e nao vem com o Studio de raiz, sendo encorajada a migração para o Firedac.

Também no site é facil de encontrar os passos para fazer a instalação.

Comment: Obrigado cara. Me ajudou a encontrar um caminho para resolver este problema. No site da embarcadero não consegui achar, mas consegui no google. Vlw.